# Setting variables per environment electron-react app

Tags: reactjs, electron

its the first time i do electron app,
this app need to do API calls to lets say:

```
http:/<baseUrl>/someAPI
```

I need to change this "baseURL" on build somehow. 
(can be anything...) 
and cant use System.env when app is build.
i am using electron builder

I am thinking about creating a script and adding it to "package.json",
any thing more simple?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use proxy in `package.json`
Example
`"proxy": "http://example.com"`
so in each HTTP request will assign this proxy in the URL.
or you can use this package [electron-proxy-agent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-proxy-agent)